# Not working in move_uploaded_file for For Loop

Tags: php

```
for($i=0;$i<count($sentto1);$i++)
 {           
 $sel="insert into newmessage set sendto='".$sentto1[$i]."', 
                                  sendfrom='".$almemailid."',
                                  subject='".$subject."',
                     message='".$color."',
                     attac='".$fileatt_name."', 
                     updateddate = now()";

      $selqur=mysql_query($sel) or die("Error (" . mysql_errno() .")" . mysql_error());
      $lastid_id = mysql_insert_id();
     $folderpath = "Attachment/".$lastid_id."".$fileatt_name;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachcopy"]["tmp_name"],$folderpath);
  }
```

Please help me.
In the above program move_uploaded_file works well in single iteration,
how i insert multiple file to store in folder (Folder Name:Attachment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move_uploaded_file removes the original file, so it doesn't exist on the second iteration, using copy after the first iteration will work.

```
$uploaded = false;
for($i=0;$i<count($sentto1);$i++)
 {           
 $sel="insert into newmessage set sendto='".$sentto1[$i]."', 
                                  sendfrom='".$almemailid."',
                                  subject='".$subject."',
                     message='".$color."',
                     attac='".$fileatt_name."', 
                     updateddate = now()";

      $selqur=mysql_query($sel) or die("Error (" . mysql_errno() .")" . mysql_error());
      $lastid_id = mysql_insert_id();
     $folderpath = "Attachment/".$lastid_id."".$fileatt_name;
     if ($uploaded)
     {
         copy($uploaded, $folderpath);
     }
     else
     {
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachcopy"]["tmp_name"],$folderpath))
         {
             $uploaded = $folderpath;
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Am Rajesh thank yuo for reply , In your code working well in adding multiple file

Comment: My page creates a folder to hold the uploaded files in which can be deleted.
BUT once the uploaded file is transfered to this folder I can neither delete the upload file or folder even though they are on my computer.

Comment: Hi,My page creates a folder to hold the uploaded files in which can be deleted.
BUT once the uploaded file is transfered to this folder I can't delete the upload file. plz reply me any php code.

Comment: Apache will be the owner of the file.  Do you wish to delete the file with php?